# SSH a travez de un Bastion/proxy con netmiko

Tags: python

Como estan comunidad? estoy intentando resolver una conexion ssh pero no logro encontrar nada concreto en internet, normalmente al intentar conectarte con netmiko utilizas datos basicos como ip, puerto, etc:

```
sandbox_cisco = {
    "device_type":"juniper",
    "host":"router01",
    "port":22,
    "username":"admin",
    "password":"admin"
    }
```

Luego utilizas comandos como estos:

```
net_connect = ConnectHandler(sandbox_cisco)
cmd2 = net_connect.send_command("show configuration |match host-name | display set")
net_connect.disconnect()
print(cmd2)
```

hasta ahi todo perfecto porque estas teniendo una conexion directa, pero en mi caso estoy intentando hacerlo desde un bastion que me hace una pregunta "yes/no"(cuando te conectas por primera vez luego no lo pregunta mas) y luego me pregunta la ip/hostname del equipo al q quiero conectarme y no se como hacerlo, imprimo la situacion:

```
PS C:\Users\Tinchou!>  ssh mebarbie@11.111.11.111 -p 8022

The authenticity of host '[11.111.11.111]:8022 ([11.111.11.111]:8022)' can't be 
established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.
This host key is known by the following other names/addresses:
C:\Users\Tinchou!/.ssh/known_hosts:4: [11.111.11.111]:8022
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
Warning: Permanently added '[11.111.11.111]:8022' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.

(mebarbie@1.111.11.111) Password:


Nokia Proxy 18.2.2.6

============================================================================
  AVISO: ha accedido a un sistema propiedad privada.
============================================================================

(mebarbie@11.111.11.111) neId: router01
--- JUNOS 20.1R3.7 Kernel 64-bit  JNPR-11.0-20210308.e5f5942_buil
{master}
PROXY_NAKINA@router01-re0>
```

Existe algun tipo de forma de poder saltear esto?

Saludos!

Comment: Si, existe una forma de almacenar las credenciales para que ssh no te las pidas cada vez. Para eso se usan llave públicas. Google "ssh generar llave" y sigue las instrucciones.

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque no es un problema de programación sino de preparación del medio ambiente.

Comment: Yo no necesito almacenar credenciales, yo necesito que alguien q use la libreria de netmiko me pueda ayudar a entender como se realizan las conexiones a travez de un proxy.

Comment: La consulta "netmiko uses ssh implementation" produce varios resultados, como https://www.charleslabri.com/python-misc-netmiko-and-using-ssh-proxies/